# asp.net menu control hide items if longer than page width

Tags: asp.net, html, css, menu

Ok I have an asp.net menu control which is created from codebehind.  It works great but this is more for a user experience than functionality.  If I resize my browser or my resolution is lower than what it was designed for then what happens is items that don't fit in the line get pushed down to a second line.  I would like to avoid that and simply hide items that won't fit because of resolution.  I hope it's clear here's my code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="navigation" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="topmenu" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="20"  
 IncludeStyleBlock="false">
 <DynamicSelectedStyle />
 <DynamicMenuItemStyle />
 <DynamicHoverStyle  />
 <DynamicMenuStyle   />
 <StaticMenuItemStyle  />
 <StaticSelectedStyle />
 <StaticHoverStyle  />
 </asp:Menu>
```

css

```
div.topmenu{}
div.topmenu ul
{
  list-style:none; 
  padding:5px 0; 
  margin:0;
  background: #0b2e56;

}
div.topmenu ul li
{
  float:left; 
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff; 
  height:16px; 
  z-index:9999;
  margin:0;

}

div.topmenu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited{ color: #fff;  }

div.topmenu ul li a:hover{ color:#fff;  }

div.topmenu ul li a:active{color:#fff;  }
```

Comment: The CSS goes with your HTML, so show your HTML, not your .net source code.

Comment: the html is what is above, in .net that's how a menu control is built.  Source code would be to show how I bind that menu control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try wrapping it in another div something like

```
<div id="navWrapper">
    <asp:Menu ID="navigation" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="topmenu" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="20"  
     IncludeStyleBlock="false">
     <DynamicSelectedStyle />
     <DynamicMenuItemStyle />
     <DynamicHoverStyle  />
     <DynamicMenuStyle   />
     <StaticMenuItemStyle  />
     <StaticSelectedStyle />
     <StaticHoverStyle  />
     </asp:Menu>
</div>
```

then alter the css like so

```
div.topmenu{}
div.topmenu ul
{
  list-style:none; 
  padding:5px 0; 
  margin:0;
  background: #0b2e56;
  float: left;
  width: 1000px;    
}
div.topmenu ul li
{
  float:left; 
  padding:10px;
  color: #fff; 
  height:16px; 
  z-index:9999;
  margin:0;

}

div.topmenu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited{ color: #fff;  }

div.topmenu ul li a:hover{ color:#fff;  }

div.topmenu ul li a:active{color:#fff;  }

#navWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```

hopefully that makes sense. I've not been able to test but use that theory and you should be set as the outer div will shrink up and hide the content as it gets smaller but the ul will stay a fixed 1000px inside that div, so won't drop down as it shinks

Comment: here is a screenshot of what the error is even after adding your css suggestion http://iminds.pe/menu.png
also when i added you css the submenus aren't showing up anymore.

Comment: can you whack the source code from the menu into http://www.jsfiddle.net and I'll give it a look over

Comment: i can give it a shot, I haven't used jsfiddle.

Comment: just be sure to push save and copy and paste the address back here for me to see what you've done :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XGYQ9/ here's the link but for some reason it doesn't even show right. i copied the html code generate by the compile(view source) and added the css

Comment: there's quite a lot of css missing from that. popup, level1, level2... etc

Comment: that's how .net compiles and puts it out there but my css that i've had takes care of that and does it accordingly..for the most part.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XGYQ9/1/ Hopefully that'll be enough to get it to work? Lemme know

Comment: thanks let me try it out, i'll play around with the css for a bit but from the looks of it .net is making it move around if resized :S

Comment: Hope you manage to get it sorted. It's deffo a css issue and you will definatly need to add an outer wrapper with overflow: hidden and 100% width and the child of that wrapper to have a fixed width for it to hide the content without knocking it down. Have a look again at my first example jsfiddle.net/kP7Zx again to see what I mean a little more :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm playing around with the css and now I have to also add an option to view more if it's hidden..what a pain! lol thanks for all your help.